# Counting combinations for specified requirement

Tags: discrete-mathematics

i want to know the regular way to count something like this
assuming i have 2 of Xs and 2 of Ys.

I want to know the total number of combination for these input.

For this example it should be 
xxyy
xyxy
xyyx
yxxy
yxyx
yyxx

So the answer is 6.

however, what I need to know is the number of combination when there is 10 Xs and 10Ys.

Is there any math's tool can compute it?

Comment: Do you know about factorials? Permutations and combinations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of ways to arrange $10$ Xs and $10$ Ys is the same as choosing $10$ positions from $20$ to place the Xs in, and filling the rest with Y. Therefore the answer is $20 \choose 10$ (if you haven't seen this notation before, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient). You can compute this with your calculator or any math tool online (such as Wolfram Alpha).

Comment: @SKLTFZ what part is incorrect?